# GeometryReader size as subview

Tags: swiftui

At an early stage of **SwiftUI**, it was easy to frame a view relative to its parent. That's gone, and we're left with `GeometryReader`.
I'll start with `GeometryReader` as the parent: It position its subview in the top left and that's fine.

As a subview, its size is unclear. The idea is to avoid giving 'hardcoded' height. Here's an image, wrapped in a `GeometryReader`, where I attempt to set a `Text` view under the image:

```
struct ContentView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Image("image")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.8)
            }
            .background(Color.green)
            Text("Text under image")
            Spacer() // I'm being ignored
        }
    }
}
```

[image: GeometryReader plain]

The `GeometryReader` has taking higher priority than the `Spacer`. At this point I can only give `GeometryReader` a hardcoded hight.

Let's try `scaledToFit()`:

```
VStack {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        Image("image")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.8)
    }
    .background(Color.green)
    .scaledToFit() // Scaled to fit 'something', who knows
    Text("Text under image")
    Spacer()
}
```

[image: GeometryReader scaled to fit]

Unless `GeometryReader` is the top 'view':

```
struct ContentViewSuper: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            VStack {
                Image("image")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.8)
                Text("Text under image")
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}
```

[image: GeometryReader as superview]

What's the right way to size `GeometryReader`? Use hardcode height? Use as the parent view of the screen? Is there another way to create a subview with `GeometryReader` that is more predictable in size?

Comment: Why are you using GeometryReader if you are not using the proxy value it gives you?

Comment: @LuLuGaGa This is just a sample. In the real project I use it to set the image size as a percentage of its parent.

Comment: I don't understand - what do you mean by "work with `GeometryReader`? What do you want to do with it? You've shown a few options - which one is what you're actually after?

Comment: @NewDev Simple. I want to use `GeometryReader` in a subview where it actually fit its content. My first example have an `Image` where I want to position a `Text` just below. I need `GeometryReader` to size the image, but `GeometryReader` is grabbing the whole screen. Must I set a hardcode height (like 100? 220? maybe 80?)? It will also look different on different devices.

Comment: I'm still confused. Size of what space/container do you want `GeometryReader` to give you? And what will you the size for? But even more broader - forget `GeometryReader` for a second - what do you want to achieve in the end in terms of layout? Are you trying to create a Image + Text card-like view and size it relative to (width?) of its parent?

Comment: @NewDev Kind of. In my original project, the original image size was too small, I had to size it bigger in code. The screen had an image on top (centering was not an issue), and other elements right below (`VStack`). I had a really hard time using relative size. I eventually gave up and just used hardcode magic number. It will look different on different devices. (BTW, updated the question to use the proxy)

Comment: For that I don't think you need a geometry reader. Just use `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)` and I think it size-up to fit into the parent. Instead of `0.8`, padding is probably the best approach here. You might find this useful: https://swiftui-lab.com/geometryreader-to-the-rescue/

Comment: @NewDev I actually read 'geometryreader-to-the-rescue' and many other before posting. Using `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)` is exactly what it is, does not directly address size. With padding, I end up with the exact issue, unless using default padding, I'll use magic numbers, which is possibly the way to go. In my App I did eventually used hardcode number for the image `width` with `aspectRatio`.

Answer (score 0):

Until a better answer comes along, this is what I have:

`GeometryReader` is <s>*meant*</s> best used as either the superview (not a subview), or a `background` view layout. Otherwise, a specific size (height) needs to be used.
`GeometryReader` will use *flexible preferred* size, it will not wrap its content. The size will behave differently than other views (higher tolerance to `Spacer` for example).

Used as a superview, the geometry, similar to `UIKit`, will place the (0,0) origin at the top left.

Comment: GeometryReader is "not as bugged" when used at the top level, you meant... otherwise it's completely wrong. Take this simple example: ```VStack { View, View, GemoetryReader { VStack { View, View, View }.frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height }, *VIEW* }```. In that example, I didn't fine a way on this planet to correctly position (vertically, I mean) the last VIEW consistently across different devices.

Comment: To this day, many coding months later, I have not **once** came back to `GemoetryReader`. I've learned to make peace with using constant values for frames in some cases (things should not look 'zoomed' on different sizes, bigger relative view on smaller device is a good thing sometimes). With UIKit, we sometimes 'injected' a 'parent size'. Honestly, I forgot all about `GemoetryReader`.